# template class type conversion

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning about templating in C++ and I'm trying to write a template class to handle different data types in order to read a configuration text file formatted in a way similar to

TYPE,DEFAULT_VALUE

I defined the following class

```
template <class T>
class option_t
{
public:

  option_t(std::string _type, std::string _defaultValue);

  //~option_t();

  std::string get_type();

  T get_defaultValue();

private:

  T defaultValue;
};

template <class T>
option_t<T>::option_t(std::string _type,std::string _defaultValue)
{
  type = _type;

  if( type.compare("integer") == 0)
  {
    defaultValue = std::stoi(_defaultValue);
  }
  else if(type.compare("real") == 0)
  {
    char *pEnd;
    defaultValue = std::strtod(_defaultValue.c_str(),&pEnd);
  }
  else if( type.compare("boolean") == 0 )
  {
    std::transform(_defaultValue.begin(),_defaultValue.end(),_defaultValue.begin(),::tolower);
    if(_defaultValue.compare("true") == 0  ||
       _defaultValue.compare("1") == 0 ||
       _defaultValue.compare("on") == 0)
    {
      defaultValue = true;
    }
    else
    {
      defaultValue = false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //LOG(ERROR) << "Option " << name << " : unknown data type ( " << type << " )";
  }

template <class T>
std::string option_t<T>::get_type()
{
  return type;
}

template <class T>
T option_t<T>::get_defaultValue()
{
  return defaultValue;
}
```

and when I use the following line into my main code

```
int tmpInt = option.get_defaultValue();
```

I get a compilation error "no viable conversion from 'std::__1::basic_string' to 'int'"

What does it mean? And how can I solve it?

Thanks and sorry for the stupid question :-)

Here all rest of my code

```
class options_t
{
  public:
    options_t();
    //~options_t();

   template <class T>
   void set_option(option_t<T> option);

  private:
};

 options_t::options_t()
 {
   // read file and depending on _type create a specific option object
   std::string _type = "integer";
   std::string _defaultValue = "5";

  if(_type.compare("integer") == 0)
  {
    option_t<int> option(_type,_defaultValue);
    set_option(option);
  }
  else if(_type.compare("real") == 0)
  {
    option_t<double> option(_type,_defaultValue);
    set_option(option);
  }
  else if(_type.compare("boolean") == 0)
  {
    option_t<bool> option(_type,_defaultValue);
    set_option(option);
  }
  else if(_type.compare("string") == 0)
  {
    option_t<std::string> option(_type,_defaultValue);
    set_option(option);
  }
  else
  {
    // LOG(ERROR) << " invalid data type( " << _type << " )";
  }
}


template <class T>
void options_t::set_option(option_t<T> option)
{
  std::string _type = option.get_type();

  if(_type.compare("integer") == 0)
  {  
    int tmpInt = option.get_defaultValue();

    option_t<int> tmpOption(option.get_type(),defaultValue);
  }
  else if(_type.compare("real") == 0)
  {
    //todo;
  }
  else if(_type.compare("boolean") == 0)
  {
    //todo;
  }
  else if(_type.compare("string") == 0)
  {
    //todo;
  }
  else
  {
    // LOG(ERROR) <<  " invalid data type( " << option.get_type() << "    )";
  }
}

int main()
{
  options_t options();
}
```

Comment: add complete code. what's `option`?

Comment: option is a class object: option_t option<int>("integer","5");

Comment: should work. post complete (but minimal) code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: ok I'll copy-paste the rest of the code

Comment: not just the "rest". something that compiles (apart from the problematic line).

Comment: ok, so I copy paste all

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. I will assume that `int tmpInt` is correct.

To retrieve an `int`, `option` has to be `option_t<int>` or `option_t<T>` where `T` is convertible to `int`. Look likes you're trying to use a string.